# Add new namespace to all newly created pages in asp.net with c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, namespaces

I have required System.Text.RegularExpressions namespace to all my pages on my webproject.so want to add this namespace by default when new page is created on my project.so what i do for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add it to the web.config, and then it will not need to be specified on any page.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164642.aspx

```
<configuration>
 <system.web>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace ="System.Text.RegularExpressions" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>  
 </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom project item templates and have this template appear in the  Add New Item dialog box.

For more details see [How to: Create Item Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tsyyf0yh.aspx)

Comment: but i want to do this in my existing code.so is there any other way to do this.